# Inner join instead of what I have now

Tags: mysql

The query below does what I want but takes a long time to finish. I have been trying to write it with INNER JOIN instead but can not figure out how to do it.

```
UPDATE cf_ab_companies
SET cf_ab_companies.col_330 = (
SELECT aaa_items.amount
FROM aaa_items
WHERE aaa_items.customer = cf_ab_companies.model_id
AND aaa_items.sku = 10
);
```

cf_ab_companies.model_id is unique value in the table.

There can be several records where aa_items.customer = 314 , but aa_items.customer = 314 AND aa_item.sku = 10 may only occur once.

Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE Multiple-table syntax can be found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

using this your query would look like

```
UPDATE cf_ab_companies join
        aaa_items on aaa_items.customer =  cf_ab_companies.model_id
SET cf_ab_companies.col_330 = aaa_items.amount
WHERE aaa_items.sku = 10
;
```

Comment: That reduced the time used from 54,2 seconds to 0,81 seconds. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MySQL `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET` syntax:

```
UPDATE cf_ab_companies c
INNER JOIN aaa_items i ON i.customer = c.model_id AND i.sku = 10
SET c.cf_ab_companies.col_330 = i.aaa_items.amount
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, GMB. Problem seems to be solved by P.Salmon. I don't quite understand if INNER JOIN works different than JOIN in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
update cf_ab_companies c 
join aaa_items a on a.customer = c.model_id 
set c.col_330 = a.amount 
where a.sku = 10
```

......

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know that I could "abbreviate" table names likr that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an UPDATE FROM can help:

```
UPDATE cf_ab_companies
SET cf_ab_companies.col_330 = aaa_items.amount
FROM cf_ab_companies INNER JOIN aaa_items 
ON cf_ab_companies.model_id = aaa_items.customer AND aaa_items.sku=10
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax for mysql.